# Floated li elements from section drop onto two lines in Firefox version 24

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox

Browser testing my development site i'm having an issue, mainly on Firefox version 24. I have set the li elements inside a full width section of 100%, Inside I have 5 floated li with anchor elements set at 20% width. These all sit in place across majority of all browsers, except Firefox 24 which makes the last element drop down onto the next line. I can fix this by reducing the width, but then it obviously does not fill the wrapper width as intended. I have an additional class of .tablet-half, which moves the last two elements to take up 50% each of the wrapper at smaller sizes. I don't know if this is somehow affecting it?  The section HTML is;

```
<section class="header-cta wrapper">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/security-systems/" class="cta-box btn--info">
            <img src="http://dev5.bmpreview.co.uk/wp-content/themes/matrix/images/parking.svg" alt="parking icon">
            <p class="cta-box__headline">Parking Barriers</p>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="/access-control/" class="cta-box btn--trader">
            <img src="http://dev5.bmpreview.co.uk/wp-content/themes/matrix/images/anpr.svg" alt="anpr icon">
            <p class="cta-box__headline">ANPR</p>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="/security-fencing/" class="cta-box btn--info tablet-half">
            <img src="http://dev5.bmpreview.co.uk/wp-content/themes/matrix/images/security-fencing.svg" alt="security fencing icon">
            <p class="cta-box__headline">Security Fencing</p>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="/cctv-systems/" class="cta-box btn--trader-dark tablet-half">
            <img src="http://dev5.bmpreview.co.uk/wp-content/themes/matrix/images/cctv.svg" alt="cctv icon">
            <p class="cta-box__headline">CCTV Solutions</p>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul></section>
```

Basic styles; (i'm using box-sizing, and there is no margin/padding on the ul,li)

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
 }

.header-cta .cta-box {
 width: 20%;
 padding-right: 0.5rem;
 padding-left: 0.5rem;
}

.tablet-half  {
 width: 50%;
}
```

I have taken an image on my phone of how it looks in Firefox 24
[image]

This is the test site [url](http://dev5.bmpreview.co.uk/) where I am working, if that helps.

Comment: FF v24? The current version is 41! Are you sure you have any users on that antique? The age alone may be the reason you have this problem.

Comment: I know Rob, but it's part of a standards check we must complete where we cover every browser and it's dog!

Comment: FFv24 is part of a standard?! That's really wild. Sorry to go off on that but that's really wild.

Comment: An issue you need to check, and I'm just now looking at your markup, is whether FF24 supported HTML5 elements back in 2013 when it was released.